# Can't get JSON data from file from local domain URL (Django static file)

Tags: javascript, json, django, d3.js, cross-domain

I want to load data from a JSON file to use with d3.js

I'm using Django and the URL of the the JSON file `json_path` looks like this:`/staticfile/example.json`. I'm using the following code to read the data and do things:

```
d3.json(json_path, function(error, data){
    // Do stuff with data
}
```

Everything works fine if I use the local IP of the server on the browser: `192.168.x.x`.

**However, when I use the local domain `foo.com` that points to `192.168.x.x`, I can't load the data anymore from `d3.json()`.** `data` is null and I can't understand the content of `error`.

I'm missing something obvious probably related to callbacks or something but I have trouble understanding the big picture. The whole Django server works perfectly well from both `192.168.x.x` and `foo.com` and everything is local. Any ideas?

`error` is:

```
XMLHttpRequest​mozAnon: false
mozSystem: false
​onabort: null
​onerror: function respond()​
onload: function respond()​
onloadend: null
​onloadstart: null
onprogress: function onprogress()​
onreadystatechange: null​
ontimeout: null​
readyState: 4
​response: ""​
responseText: ""
​responseType: ""​
responseURL: ""
​responseXML: null
​status: 0
statusText: ""
​timeout: 0​
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload { onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, … }​
withCredentials: false​
<prototype>: XMLHttpRequestPrototype { open: open(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), send: send(), … } page:472:7
```

I'm using a library that uses D3 version `3.5.2` and can't update in this particular case.

Comment: I read your question twice but didn't see the actual error message you got. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: do you have any error message? you have CORS related error message?

Comment: I added the content of `error` but it's a big javascript object, not sure how to post it properly, lots of nested objects.

Comment: @Cyrlop just the error message would be enough

Comment: There is no error message, just `data` being `null` so the rest is failing.

Comment: Are you using an older version of d3? Because the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#json) say the call looks like `d3.json(input[, init])`, *init* being optional. Your "error" is actually the `XMLHttpRequest` instance that is loading the file.

Comment: Using d3 3.5.2 and can't update. The problem is more general though, I can't load the file with regular JQuery either.

Comment: are you requesting using the same domain that your page is loaded. for instance you page is foo.com/index.html and requesting your json at foo.com/staticfile/example.json

Comment: Yes, the path is literally the one I mentioned in the question, it's not dependent on the domain, it got appended automatically to whatever domain you're using. I'll try to play around with what you answered tomorrow and keep you posted. It should give a better idea of what the error is at least.

Comment: Ok, what server are you using? Django dev server?

Comment: Yes temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

In general, D3 has not prioritized really robust AJAX support the way that jQuery and other libraries have, because that's not its focus - so if you want to load a wide variety of external resources, like json data, you should probably do so with a 3rd-party library that has more support for carefully tweaked AJAX calls.

Or simply using XMLHttpRequest wrapped in a makeRequest function:

```
function makeRequest(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", json_path, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadyStatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(error) {
        throw error;
    }
    xhr.send(); 
};

makeRequest(json_path, function(json_response) {
    //here you can use D3 to load your json as you want
    console.log(json_response);
});
```

Comment: After changing `xhr.setRequestHeader()` to `xhr.overrideMimeType()`, I end up with the same problem. On `192.168.x.x` I get `status` of 200 and a correct `response` but if in the browser I use `foo.com` I get a `status` of 0 and an empty `response`. Do you need to see specific parts of the `error` `ProgressEvent` object?

Comment: sorry there was a typo: it's suppose to be `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");`

Comment: Yes I saw that it was still not working in my case for some reason. For my problem I ended up passing the full JSON string as a variable instead of using a file, but I'm still curious about this domain problem.

Comment: Have you tried to add your domain in `ALLOWED_HOST` setting? see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: My `ALLOWED_HOST` was `['*']` but I tried to add the domain just it case and same result. I just noticed I have another app using a similar `d3.json()` command using a similar json local file and it works fine. It's probably something to do with a fancy JS library I'm using on top of D3.